# In nodejs, how trust both public certificate and self-signed certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

When https to connect server, if the ca is not set or set to null, it trust the OS default public ca cert. And when ca is set, it trust the custom self-signed ca. How to both trust default public ca and self-signed ca?

Comment: Are you talking about browser giving that warning?

Comment: no. use nodejs https to communicate a https server.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your request call to

```
var req = https.request({ 
      host: 'ip.ip.ip.ip', 
      port: 443,
      path: '/',
      method: 'GET',
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      requestCert: true,
      agent: false
    },
```

Comment: By this setting, it just ignore the self-signed certificate, right? But my request is that the client only accepts public certs and those self-signed certs that is set its ca. For example, I set ca:ca1, and I only want to let the public certs and ca1's cert go. Reject other self-signed certs.